# Very slow save operation with DynamoDB on local machine

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use `DynamoDB` on my local pc.
Before I was using `MongoDB` and the performance of the `DynamoDB`  compared to it is very poor. 
The save operation to a table takes a very long time, about 13 seconds for 100 records.
The records are pretty small, example below.
Here is my full example and code which I use to run it:

```
public class dynamoTry {
    private AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-east-2"))
            .build();
    private DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    private DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dynamoTry dt = new dynamoTry ();
        dt .deleteTable();
        dt .buildGrid();

        dt .demoFill();
        dt .scanTable();    
    }

    public void buildGrid() {
        System.out.println("Attempting to create table; please wait...");

        String tableName = "Grid";

        List<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
        attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("name").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));
        attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("country").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S));

        List<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
        keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("name").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));
        keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("country").withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE));

        CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(tableName).withKeySchema(keySchema)
                .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions).withProvisionedThroughput(
                    new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(500L).withWriteCapacityUnits(500L));

        Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request);

        try {
            table.waitForActive();
            System.out.println("Success.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public void demoFill() {
        final List<GridPoint> gpl = new ArrayList<GridPoint>();
        int count = 0;

        while (count < 100) {
            final String point = "point" + count;

            gpl.add(makeGP(point, count, "continent", "country", new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(22.23435, 37.89746))));

            count++;
        }

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        addBatch(gpl);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000; 
        System.out.println(duration + " [ms]");
    }

    public void addBatch(List<GridPoint> gpl) {
        mapper.batchSave(gpl);
    }

    public GridPoint makeGP(String name, int sqNum, String continent, String country, HashSet<Double> cords) {
        GridPoint item = new GridPoint();
        item.setName(name);
        item.setSqNum(sqNum);
        item.setContinent(continent);
        item.setCountry(country);
        item.setCoordinates(cords);

        return item;
    }

    public void scanTable() {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        eav.put(":val", new AttributeValue().withN("0"));
        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression().withFilterExpression("sqNum >= :val").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
        List<GridPoint> scanResult = mapper.scan(GridPoint.class, scanExpression);
        for (GridPoint gp : scanResult) {
            System.out.println(gp);
        }
    }

    public void deleteTable() {
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Grid");

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to delete table 'Grid', please wait...");
            table.delete();
            table.waitForDelete();
            System.out.print("Success.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to delete table: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the `GridPoint` class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Grid")
public class GridPoint {
    private String name;
    private int sqNum;
    private String continent;
    private String country;
    private HashSet<Double> coordinates; // [longitude, latitude]

    // Partition key
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "sqNum")
    public int getSqNum() {
        return sqNum;
    }
    public void setSqNum(int sqNum) {
        this.sqNum = sqNum;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "continent")
    public String getContinent() {
        return continent;
    }
    public void setContinent(String continent) {
        this.continent = continent;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "coordinates")
    public HashSet<Double> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(HashSet<Double> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GP {name = " + name + ", sqNum = " + sqNum + ", continent = " + continent + ", country = " + country
            + ", coordinates = " + coordinates.toString() + "}";
    }

}
```

Why is it so slow? is there any way of speeding the writing process?
In `MongoDB` the same operations would take less than a second.
When I was running it about 3000 points it took several minutes to finish, seems not reasonable.
Is it possible to make the batch save process parallel? would it speed things up?
I also tried to set the `ProvisionedThroughput` parameter to a higher value but that did not help.
I am lost, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is not answering your question but why are you using a HashSet to store coordinates? A set is typically not sorted so you can't know which one is lattitude or longitude

Comment: I guess I saw that in some example. How would you recommend to store it? It should be a set of doubles after all.

Comment: Most sets are not sorted so {x,y}={y,x}, then there's no way to tell which element of the set is x and which is y. And what if your set somehow contains 3 values, because of a bug? It would make more sense to me to have two attributes (as you already have country, continent attributes), lattitude and longitude.

Comment: Ok, fair point. Still, as you said it does not explain the very long time of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is slow because it is not DynamoDB. There is no Local DynamoDB!

DynamoDB is a managed service provided by AWS and it is really fast (milliseconds for the first bytes), highly scalable and durable. It is a really good product with a lot of performance for a small amount of money. But it is a managed service. It only works on AWS environment. There is no way to you or anyone else get a copy and install DynamoDB in Azure, GCP or even in your local environment.

What are you using is a facade, probably developed by AWS Team to help developers test their applications. There are other DynamoDB facades, not developed by AWS Team but everyone of then just respect a protocol that accepts all api calls from the original product. As a facade, his objective is just provide a endpoint that can receive your calls and respond like the original product. If you make a call that the original DynamoDB would respond with an Ok the facade will respond with an Ok. If you make a call that the original DynamoDB would respond with a failure the facade will send you a failure.

There is no compromisse with performance or even data durability. If you need a durable database, with good performance, you must go with MongoDB. DynamoDB was created to be used on AWS environment only.

Again: There is no such thing like DynamoDB local.

Comment: What you say Gustavo is mostly correct. The DynamoDB local does exist, but it is ONLY for developing code against and function testing. It is definitely not meant for performance testing by any means, much less production deployment. The one distributed by AWS is written by the DynamoDB team, but like you basically said, it is a stand it so you can develop anywhere, and then deploy against the real DynamoDB in AWS.

Comment: Ok, Kirk already corrected me about DynamoDB local existence. Sorry about that, and thanks Kirk for the correction. Just to confirm Kirk's information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/) are something that was published after my response by AWS Team. So, sorry again for the emphasis and please do not consider the second phrase of the first paragraph and the the last phrase of my response.

Answer (score -1):

DynamoDB has predefined [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html). It is possible that you are running into these limits. Consider increasing `WriteCapacityUnits` for the table to increase performance. You may also want to increase `ReadCapacityUnits` for the scan.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question

Comment: "Why is it so slow? is there any way of speeding the writing process?" By increasing the WriteCapacityUnits you can speed up the write process.

Comment: this question is not about dynamodb on AWS, it's about the local version of dynamodb

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand now. So to be clear is the questioner is using the aws  [local product](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html). This was not made obvious in the question or in your first comment.